# motd login message won't save after restart

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

For some reason I edited motd file yesterday from the standard "Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY..." to my own customized message. After a system restart today, my customized message is gone and it's back to:

```
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
```

How can I make my own message permanent? BTW, I am using Debian 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debian has `/etc/motd` as a symlink to `/var/run/motd` by default. This is updated at boot by `/etc/init.d/bootlogs`.

To use your own motd simply break the `/etc/motd` symlink and create it as a regular file.

Answer (score 1):

No, after an Dist-upgrade you have the old motd. I think the best way is to use the`/etc/motd.tail` and you can take some additional informations in it.

Comment: dpkg shouldn't silently replace files - it generally asks first. As `/etc/motd.tail` is supplied by a Debian package it's more likely that this will get overwritten.

Comment: ah, yeah - you are right. It asks first and many more times the answer is "yes". I always goes the motd.tail way.